How to test a Pydantic BaseModel with MagicMock spec and wraps
Given this example in Python 3.8, using Pydantic v2:
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    a: str = '123'

    # the actual implementation has many intertwined attributes
    # and methods that I'd like to test

@pytest.fixture(name='myclass')
def fixture_myclass():
    yield MagicMock(wraps=MyClass(), spec=MyClass)

def test_myclass_wraps(myclass):
    assert myclass.a == '123'

Running this will raise:
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'a'
I expect attribute access to pass through the wrapper here. However, since Pydantic uses metaclass trickery to not store attributes and methods normally until after instantiation, a doesn't exist in dir or myclass.__dict__. I think this is why the spec doesn't work the way I expect, since MagicMock uses dir under the hood to inspect the attributes on an object. So, it's unable to spec the instance properly because of how Pydantic stores stuff.
So how can I mock a BaseModel class? I would like to use spec for test safety and wraps for simplifying the amount of manual mocking.

I'm running into the same problem. I tried creating a factory that would iterate over the model_fields and construct a mock with those attributes, before using that mock as a spec for the final one returned. Seemed hacky and I couldn't figure out how to handle any nested pydantic models. I'm working around this by not using spec on the mocks, which is unfortunate.

It's a bit of a pain but you can also pass a list of strings of the expected methods/attributes. So you would instantiate the Mock while setting spec to the dir + model_fields
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    a: str = '123'

    # the actual implementation has many intertwined attributes
    # and methods that I'd like to test

@pytest.fixture(name='myclass')
def fixture_myclass():
    yield MagicMock(wraps=MyClass(), spec=dir(MyClass) + list(MyClass.model_fields.keys()))

def test_myclass_wraps(myclass):
    assert myclass.a == '123'

Note that you will lose the ability to pass isinstance checks due to using a list of strings. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock
Also note that this example will still fail since attribute access on a mock will return a mock (and not the default value of '123' defined in the model). However, that is a different issue.

Why not just create a model instead of mocking?
import pytest
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    a: str = '123'


@pytest.fixture(name='myclass')
def fixture_myclass():
    yield MyClass()


def test_myclass_wraps(myclass):
    assert myclass.a == '123'

If you need to configure factories for dynamic use, then I recommend polyfactory
from pydantic import BaseModel

from polyfactory.factories.pydantic_factory import ModelFactory


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: float
    height: float
    weight: float


class PersonFactory(ModelFactory[Person]): ...


def test_is_person() -> None:
    person_instance = PersonFactory.build()
    assert isinstance(person_instance, Person)
    assert isinstance(person_instance.name, str)
    assert isinstance(person_instance.age, float)
    assert isinstance(person_instance.height, float)
    assert isinstance(person_instance.weight, float)


In the actual code, MyClass is much more complicated. It has several functions and uses BaseModel mainly for type validation. Since I'm trying to unittest those functions and they're not pure, I need to do lots of function mocks in every test. I'm trying to avoid typing those out manually, so I can have the safety of spec.

I think you should set the attributes in your mock class manually. At least, that's also how I always do this. I even do prefer this, since then I know the values of these attributes, and the tests are not affected when a becomes "789" (assuming that value is not important for the functionality of course). I can even parameterise multiple values.
Yes, in case you have a complicated class like you said, it's a bit more work, but still...it makes your test more predictable I think.
On the bright side, methods are recognised the way you've implemented this. So the test below passes.
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    a: str = '123'

    def _foo(self):
        return 'bar'

    def _baz(self):
        return self.a

    # the actual implementation has many intertwined attributes
    # and methods that I'd like to test


@pytest.fixture(name='myclass')
def fixture_myclass():
    my_mock_class = MagicMock(wraps=MyClass(), spec=MyClass)
    my_mock_class.a = '456'  # set the attribute
    my_mock_class._baz.return_value = '789'  # test a different output for _baz
    yield my_mock_class


def test_myclass_wraps(myclass):
    assert myclass.a == '456'
    assert myclass._foo() == 'bar'  # this was not mocked
    assert myclass._baz() == '789'  # this was mocked

